# How to pass automation test case data from TFS to Protractor using Cucumber/Jasmine

Tags: protractor, jasmine, tfs, typescript

I am using Visual Studio Code, Protractor, Typescript and Jasmine to build test cases fro Angular website. I need to pick test data from Team Foundation server(TFS) only.
It was possible in Coded UI with Visual studio.
Just wondering if its possible in case of Protractor as well.

Comment: Hi how are you accessing tfs data , as from cucumber data driven is achieved through  scenario outline which doesn't support external files . But in step definition you can implement any logic.

Comment: Step definition is the protractor code

Comment: Hi, I am unable to access data from TFS using Protractor as of now and finding a way to do that. You are right from Step definition I can access the data from scenarios outline, however wondering if test data can be fetched from TFS (since TFS contains my automation test cases data) using Jasmine/Protractor. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you took tfs data before in any other tools ?

Comment: Yes, Coded UI was using Team foundation Server to fetch automation test case data.

Comment: fetch means test data is in another database ? Or file like csv ? . Then you could right JavaScript code to get that data and iterate over it  and call the IT function in each iteration

Comment: do you have any documentation showing how test data is stored in tfs or how it is retrieved

Comment: In TFS, we have written automation test cases where we have provided data in each test case.I need to pass the test case id and parameters from TFS to our Typescript test script. So we'll fetch data directly from TFS instead of any excel file. I need to know how to get this data using Typescript/Jasmine.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to store test data in tfs . Is there any documentation available ?

Answer (score 1):

TSF exposes HTTP endpoints from which you can fetch data.

You can find examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38476702/2252076) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bdb9f7cc-8e5a-4cc1-85c9-735947353754/team-foundation-server-api-documentation).